# User defined language issue when highlighting

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to use custom syntax highlighting for files that goes something like this:

```
Image
    Name    MyImage
    File    MyImage.png
end
```

In the **Folder & Default** tab of the **User Defined Language** window, on **Folding in code 1 style** I have the word **Image** (among others, separated by blank spaces) in **open**, and the word **end** in **close**.

It works fine, since I can fold/unfold the block starting in **image** and ending in **end**. But the problem is that is taking My**Image** and My**Image**.png as opening words too.

I don't see any option to specify that the word **Image** should match the whole word. It seems it's due to the fact that the property definitions are not quoted as strings.

Is there any work around that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Folding in code 2 style (separators needed)` instead.

[As explained here](http://udl20.weebly.com/folding-in-code.html), it requires white space separation for the keywords.