# Notepad++ highlights middle of name because of keyword?

Tags: notepad++, customization, highlighting, user-defined

I have a custom language defined in Notepad++, which has a few "open/close" folding delimiters.

**Openers are:**

```
define do if
```

**Closers are:**

```
endmethod endfunction endobject enddo endif
```

---

But when I create the following text, the "if" part inside of the method name gets wrongly highlighted, and all the subsequent foldings are messed up:

> define method .mod**IF**yform()

How do I avoid that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43787963/694733

Comment: If you'd like to post it as an answer, that's ok :) -- I couldn't find that topic before....

Comment: If that question has the answer that fits, it would be better if you close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User defined language issue when highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787963/user-defined-language-issue-when-highlighting)